# Bad label placing in kiviat diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-kiviat

[image]
[image]

Shouldn't `\resizebox` resize the label along with the whole picture? How can I avoid the label being put above the arrow (other than rotating the image, which I don't want to do)?

```
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[label distance=.5cm]{{Kolerikus},{Szangvinikus},{Melankolikus},{Flegmatikus}}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](5.0,2.30769230769,4.66666666667,4.16666666667
    )
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=10,suffix=\ \%](1)
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Vérmérséklet}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you are going to downvote something, please provide a reason so that the OP has a chance to correct the issue.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Yes, it should. Doesn’t it? Have you tried your example without the `\resizebox`? Is the label still position over the arrow? Please provide a fully compilable MWE (without `\resizebox` if that isn't part of the problem). For example, I get another picture than yours with a standard preamble. By the way `label distance` is not a style that affects the outcome of the `\tkzKiviatDiagram` macro. Maybe you meant `label space`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t get that faulty output with the following standard preamble (with and without `\resizebox`).

But as the `label style` is pre-defined with `text width=2cm` the horizontal spacing for `Melankolikus` and `Kolerikus` will be different as `Kolerikus` is thinner and has thus more space to its arrow. I suggest (at least in this case) to use a a fixed spacing with the following adjustment:

```
\pgfkeys{/kiviat/label style/.style={align=center,anchor=180+360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang}}
```

The [`tikzscale` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzscale) help with scaling a TikZ picture to a fixed width *but* without re-sizing font sizes and line widths. Unfortunately (?) the TikZ picture then has to be provided in an extra file with the extension `.tikz`.

(The standard `article` class will give a overfull hbox warning as the `\textwidth` is slightly smaller than `12cm`. It is probably advisable to use `width=\textwidth` either way.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[label space=.5]{Kolerikus,Szangvinikus,Melankolikus,Flegmatikus}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](5.0,2.30769230769,4.66666666667,4.16666666667)
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=10,suffix=\ \%](1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/kiviat/label style/.style={align=center,anchor=180+360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{\jobname.tikz}
\end{document}
```

### (Unresized) Output

[image]